# select value that occurs most frequently by group

Tags: sparql

I have RDF data about hospital patients, including their date of birth.  There are frequently **multiple triples abut their date of birth**, and **some of those triples may be wrong**.  My group has decided to use this rule:  **whatever date occurs most frequently will provisionally be considered correct**.  It's clear how to do this in any programming language of our choice, external to SPARQL.

*Is an aggregation of aggregations possible in SPARQL?*

I have read the similar question  [SPARQL selecting MAX value of a counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912861/sparql-selecting-max-value-of-a-counter), but I'm not there yet.

---

Given these triples:

```
@prefix turbo: <http://example.org/ontologies/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<http://example.org/ontologies/b6be95364ec943af2ef4ab161c11c855>
  a <http://example.org/ontologies/StudyPartWithBBDonation> ;
  turbo:hasBirthDateO turbo:3950b2b6-f575-4074-b0e8-f9fa3378f3be, turbo:4250aafa-4b0c-4f73-92b6-7639f427b61d, turbo:a3e6676e-a214-4af4-b8ef-34a8e20170bf .

turbo:3950b2b6-f575-4074-b0e8-f9fa3378f3be turbo:hasDateValue "1971-12-30"^^xsd:date .
turbo:4250aafa-4b0c-4f73-92b6-7639f427b61d turbo:hasDateValue "1971-12-30"^^xsd:date .
turbo:a3e6676e-a214-4af4-b8ef-34a8e20170bf turbo:hasDateValue "1971-12-30"^^xsd:date .
turbo:6e200ca0d5150282787464a2bda55814
  a turbo:StudyPartWithBBDonation ;
  turbo:hasBirthDateO turbo:b09519f5-b123-40d5-bb4a-737ec9f8b9a8, turbo:06c56881-a6c7-4d1d-993b-add8862dffd7, turbo:12ef184d-c8d6-4d93-a558-a3ba47bb56ca .

turbo:b09519f5-b123-40d5-bb4a-737ec9f8b9a8 turbo:hasDateValue "2000-04-04"^^xsd:date .
turbo:06c56881-a6c7-4d1d-993b-add8862dffd7 turbo:hasDateValue "2000-04-04"^^xsd:date .
turbo:12ef184d-c8d6-4d93-a558-a3ba47bb56ca turbo:hasDateValue "2000-04-05"^^xsd:date .
```

This query

```
PREFIX  turbo: <http://example.org/ontologies/>
SELECT  ?part ?xsddate (COUNT(?xsddate) AS ?datecount) 
  { ?part  rdf:type             turbo:StudyPartWithBBDonation ;
           turbo:hasBirthDateO  ?dob .
    ?dob   turbo:hasDateValue   ?xsddate
  }
GROUP BY ?part ?xsddate
```

gives the following:

```
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------+
|                  part                  |        xsddate         |    datecount     |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------+
| turbo:6e200ca0d5150282787464a2bda55814 | "2000-04-05"^^xsd:date | "1"^^xsd:integer |
| turbo:b6be95364ec943af2ef4ab161c11c855 | "1971-12-30"^^xsd:date | "3"^^xsd:integer |
| turbo:6e200ca0d5150282787464a2bda55814 | "2000-04-04"^^xsd:date | "2"^^xsd:integer |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------+
```

**I only want to see the date with the highest count for each patient who is participating in a study:**

```
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------+
|                  part                  |        xsddate         |    datecount     |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------+
| turbo:b6be95364ec943af2ef4ab161c11c855 | "1971-12-30"^^xsd:date | "3"^^xsd:integer |
| turbo:6e200ca0d5150282787464a2bda55814 | "2000-04-04"^^xsd:date | "2"^^xsd:integer |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------+
```

**I think I'm getting close here.  Now I need to get the counts and max counts on the same row!**

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  turbo: <http://example.org/ontologies/>

SELECT  ?part ?xsddate ?datecount ?countmax
WHERE
  {   { SELECT  ?part ?xsddate (COUNT(?xsddate) AS ?datecount)
        WHERE
          { ?part  rdf:type             turbo:StudyPartWithBBDonation ;
                   turbo:hasBirthDateO  ?dob .
            ?dob   turbo:hasDateValue   ?xsddate
          }
        GROUP BY ?part ?xsddate
      }
    UNION
      { SELECT  ?part (MAX(?datecount) AS ?countmax)
        WHERE
          { SELECT  ?part ?xsddate (COUNT(?xsddate) AS ?datecount)
            WHERE
              { ?part  rdf:type             turbo:StudyPartWithBBDonation ;
                       turbo:hasBirthDateO  ?dob .
                ?dob   turbo:hasDateValue   ?xsddate
              }
            GROUP BY ?part ?xsddate
          }
        GROUP BY ?part
      }
  }
```

giving

```
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------+------------------+
|                  part                  |        xsddate         |    datecount     |     countmax     |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------+------------------+
| turbo:6e200ca0d5150282787464a2bda55814 | "2000-04-05"^^xsd:date | "1"^^xsd:integer |                  |
| turbo:b6be95364ec943af2ef4ab161c11c855 | "1971-12-30"^^xsd:date | "3"^^xsd:integer |                  |
| turbo:6e200ca0d5150282787464a2bda55814 | "2000-04-04"^^xsd:date | "2"^^xsd:integer |                  |
| turbo:6e200ca0d5150282787464a2bda55814 |                        |                  | "2"^^xsd:integer |
| turbo:b6be95364ec943af2ef4ab161c11c855 |                        |                  | "3"^^xsd:integer |
+----------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: I have updated my answer: if you are using Blazegraph, you can use named subqueries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you need just to replace `UNION` with `.` in your query (or you could just remove this `UNION`, as @AKSW has pointed out in the comment below).

In GraphDB, however, your will recieve an error:

> Variable `?datecount` is already used in a previous projection. Bindings
>   are not propagated through projections since Sesame 2.8, so this may
>   lead to logical errors in the query.

Thus, change your query in this way:

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  turbo: <http://example.org/ontologies/>

SELECT  ?part ?xsddate ?datecount_ ?countmax
WHERE
  {   { SELECT  ?part ?xsddate (COUNT(?xsddate) AS ?datecount_)
        WHERE
          { ?part  rdf:type             turbo:StudyPartWithBBDonation ;
                   turbo:hasBirthDateO  ?dob .
            ?dob   turbo:hasDateValue   ?xsddate
          }
        GROUP BY ?part ?xsddate
      }
      .
      { SELECT  ?part (MAX(?datecount) AS ?countmax)
        WHERE
          { SELECT  ?part ?xsddate (COUNT(?xsddate) AS ?datecount)
            WHERE
              { ?part  rdf:type             turbo:StudyPartWithBBDonation ;
                       turbo:hasBirthDateO  ?dob .
                ?dob   turbo:hasDateValue   ?xsddate
              }
            GROUP BY ?part ?xsddate
          }
        GROUP BY ?part
      }
  }
```

---

In Blazegraph, you could use [named subqueries](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/NamedSubquery):

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  turbo: <http://example.org/ontologies/>

SELECT  ?part ?xsddate ?datecount ?countmax

WITH 
  { SELECT  ?part ?xsddate (COUNT(?xsddate) AS ?datecount)
      WHERE
        { ?part  rdf:type             turbo:StudyPartWithBBDonation ;
                 turbo:hasBirthDateO  ?dob .
          ?dob   turbo:hasDateValue   ?xsddate
        }
       GROUP BY ?part ?xsddate
  } AS %sub

WHERE
  {  { SELECT ?part (MAX(?datecount) AS ?countmax)
       WHERE { INCLUDE %sub } GROUP BY ?part
     }
      INCLUDE %sub
  }
```

Comment: thanks!  I created an answer of my own to show how I can pass the conclusions back into a named graph within the triplestore.  We may end up doing this outside of SPARQL, but I'm really glad we have this option now.

Comment: Why do you need the dot here? This is - as far as I know - superfluous and not necessary as the default operation between two `GroupGraphPattern` is the join operation. Cheers.

Comment: @AKSW, you are right, this dot is superfluous. But informal "joining" semantics of `.` looks relevant here, which was the reason of my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

My elaboration on Stanislav's awesome answer

- renamed the `?datecount` in one of the `{}` patterns
- added a filter
- *inserting the consensus DOB into a named graph within the triplestore*

.

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  turbo: <http://example.org/ontologies/>

INSERT {
  GRAPH turbo:DOB_conclusions {
    ?part turbo:hasBirthDateO ?DOBconc .
    ?DOBconc turbo:hasDateValue ?xsddate .
    ?DOBconc turbo:conclusionated true .
    ?DOBconc rdf:type <http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0004950> .
  }
}
WHERE
  { { SELECT  ?part ?xsddate (COUNT(?xsddate) AS ?datecount)
      WHERE
        { ?part  rdf:type             turbo:StudyPartWithBBDonation ;
                 turbo:hasBirthDateO  ?dob .
          ?dob   turbo:hasDateValue   ?xsddate
        }
      GROUP BY ?part ?xsddate
    }
    .
    { SELECT  ?part (MAX(?datecount2) AS ?countmax)
      WHERE
        { SELECT  ?part ?xsddate (COUNT(?xsddate) AS ?datecount2)
          WHERE
            { ?part  rdf:type             turbo:StudyPartWithBBDonation ;
                     turbo:hasBirthDateO  ?dob .
              ?dob   turbo:hasDateValue   ?xsddate
            }
          GROUP BY ?part ?xsddate
        }
      GROUP BY ?part
    }
    FILTER ( ?datecount = ?countmax )
    BIND(uri(concat("http://transformunify.org/ontologies/", struuid())) AS ?DOBconc)
  }
```