# Using a result of a select inside of other select without using subselect SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I was working on a school work about queries using sparql in a dataset from imdb. I had to do some queries and I had aesthetic problem with this one:

```
SELECT ?1d ?2d WHERE {
  {
    SELECT ?d (COUNT(?d) AS ?count)
    WHERE {
      ?x projeto:actsIn ?m .

      ?x foaf-modified:firstName ?1x .
      ?x foaf-modified:familyName ?2x .

      FILTER REGEX(?1x, "^Frances?") .
      FILTER REGEX(?2x, "^Mcdormand?") .

      ?d projeto:directs ?m .
    } GROUP BY ?d
  }
  {
    SELECT (MAX(?count) AS ?max)
    WHERE {
      {
        SELECT ?d (COUNT(?d) AS ?count)
        WHERE {
          ?x projeto:actsIn ?m .

          ?x foaf-modified:firstName ?1x .
          ?x foaf-modified:familyName ?2x .

          FILTER REGEX(?1x, "^Frances?") .
          FILTER REGEX(?2x, "^Mcdormand?") .

          ?d projeto:directs ?m .
        } GROUP BY ?d
      }
    }
  }
  FILTER (?count = ?max) .

  ?d foaf-modified:firstName ?1d .
  ?d foaf-modified:familyName ?2d .
}
```

I need to get which director who most directed films of actor X (Frances Mcdormand, in this example). A solution that I found, uses the same select block with count twice. Is there any other way to do this query without using the same block twice?

Comment: Why is this a problem? If you need the max per group and the total max, then no, there isn't

Comment: @NicolasNogueira, Addressing the question title only: Blazegraph supports named queries, see e. g. the second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46101687/7879193) for an example.

Comment: @StanislavKralin This is interesting. Do you know whether this has any positive impact on the performance? I'm still wondering if common triple stores do reuse the result of subqueries.

Comment: @AKSW, AFAIK, Blazegraph executes named subqueries only once. But it seems that sometimes Blazegraph executes repeated subquery only once even if this subquery is not named (with `&explain` option, Blazegraph shows an execution plan). There is also [`hint:runOnce`](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/QueryHints) instruction.