# Get MAX result from COUNT in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I have this query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX curricula: <http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula#>
SELECT ?topic (COUNT(?x) as ?number_of_courses)
WHERE {
   ?topic curricula:taughtIn ?x .
}
GROUP BY ?topic
ORDER BY desc(?number_of_courses)
```

That returns:

[image]

Now I want to get the `?topic` with the max `?number_of_courses`, in this case `Engineering`

I managed to get the max `?number_of_courses` with this query (following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39960709/3695939)):

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX curricula: <http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula#>
SELECT (MAX(?number_of_courses) AS ?maxc)
WHERE{
  {
    SELECT ?topic (COUNT(?x) as ?number_of_courses)
    WHERE {
      ?topic curricula:taughtIn ?x .
    }
    GROUP BY ?topic
  }
}
```

This returns:

[image]

But I can't manage to get the `?topic`.

How could I fix this?

---

### Update

I tried what I understood from AKSW comment:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX curricula: <http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula#>
SELECT ?topic 
WHERE { 
  ?topic curricula:taughtIn ?x . 
  { 
    SELECT (MAX(?number_of_courses) AS ?max) 
    WHERE { 
      { 
        SELECT ?topic (COUNT(?x) as ?number_of_courses) 
        WHERE { 
           ?topic curricula:taughtIn ?x . 
         } 
         GROUP BY ?topic 
      }
    } 
  }
} 
GROUP BY ?topic
HAVING (COUNT(?x) = ?max)
```

But it returns nothing.

---

### Example

For [this minimal example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T5f0DMLH__8tvf1SFfiKKjffbsuv3EkH/view?usp=sharing) the result should be `Topic_2` since it's `taughtIn` two courses.

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula#taughtIn
:taughtIn rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
          rdfs:subPropertyOf owl:topObjectProperty .


###  http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#topObjectProperty
owl:topObjectProperty rdfs:domain :Topic ;
                      rdfs:range :Course .


#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula#Course
:Course rdf:type owl:Class ;
        owl:disjointWith :Topic .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula#Topic
:Topic rdf:type owl:Class .


#################################################################
#    Individuals
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula#Course_1
:Course_1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                   :Course .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula#Course_2
:Course_2 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                   :Course .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula#Topic_1
:Topic_1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                  :Topic ;
         :taughtIn :Course_1 .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula#Topic_2
:Topic_2 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                  :Topic ;
         :taughtIn :Course_1 ,
                   :Course_2 .


###  Generated by the OWL API (version 4.2.8.20170104-2310) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi
```

Comment: "But I can't manage to get the `?topic`" - what happens if you try?

Comment: An outer query doing the same as the most inner query combined with `HAVING (COUNT(?x) = ?max)` should do the trick.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra if I had `?topic` to the last `SELECT` it says "variable `topic` in projection not present in GROUP BY". If I add a `GROUP BY` the query returns an empty topic and maxc of "0"

Comment: @AKSW I tried what I understood from your comment and updated the question with the results, but maybe I didn't got what you mean

Comment: Well, indeed the outer query needs again what you did in the most inner query, i.e. add `?topic curricula:taughtIn ?x .`, otherwise it's clearly empty

Comment: `SELECT ?topic
WHERE {
?topic curricula:taughtIn ?x .
{ SELECT (MAX(?number_of_courses) AS ?max)
WHERE{
  {
    SELECT ?topic (COUNT(?x) as ?number_of_courses)
    WHERE {
      ?topic curricula:taughtIn ?x .
    }
    GROUP BY ?topic
  }
}
}
}
GROUP BY ?topic
HAVING (COUNT(?x) = ?max)`

Comment: @AKSW I fixed as you suggested but it still returns an empty list, if I remove the `HAVING` it returns all the topics. Could it be a problem when comparing the integers? Feel free to post this as an answer

Comment: Do you have some sample data for me such that I can check it locally? I might be wrong, that's why it'S recommended to provide a minimal sample dataset such that people here can validate their suggested method.

Comment: @AKSW as you suggested I have included a minimal sample dataset, thanks for taking your time to help me out.

Comment: well, indeed I was wrong, I forgot the join that is done with my suggestions. I guess one solution (although maybe not the most efficient one would be to do the inner subquery again and do the join on the count variable:`SELECT ?topic WHERE { {
SELECT ?topic (COUNT(?x) as ?count) WHERE { 
?topic curricula:taughtIn ?x . } GROUP BY ?topic }{ 
SELECT (MAX(?number_of_courses) AS ?count) WHERE { 
{ 
        SELECT ?topic (COUNT(?x) as ?number_of_courses) 
        WHERE { 
?topic curricula:taughtIn ?x . 
} 
GROUP BY ?topic 
      }
    } 
  }
} `

Comment: @AKSW that one works! thanks! do leave it as an answer so I can select it as the correct one